# Instant vs LocalDateTime - When to prefer one over the other

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I need to save and present datetime of events that happened in my server in UTC.
I have the option of using Instant.now() or LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)

When should I prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the data. The two types are conceptually different.

Imagine the event happened at 8am UTC.

Once you have a LocalDateTime, you have lost the time zone information and it could technically be in any time zone - so maybe 8am UTC or 8am EST (= 1pm UTC). It means that you have to "know" that your convention is that that LocalDateTime is in fact a UTC moment.

If you use an Instant, you know exactly what moment in time is being referred to, regardless of time zones, and don't need external "knowledge" or convention. However you don't have time zone information either so you don't know if it is 8am UK time of 9am CET or 3am EST (but these all represent the same moment in time).

Finally, if you need both the moment in time and with which time zone it should be associated, you could use a ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime which will have the Instant and the time zone information.

Comment: Than it seems that Instant is more suitable to be the usage for most of the flow. And only when I need to represent the information to the user I will do the conversion: LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instantValue, ZoneOffset.UTC) (I must do it because it's impossible to extract specific date and time components, like hour or day, directly from the Instant type)

Comment: Yes that would make sense.

Comment: Frankly speaking, seems that LocalDateTime, intended as a time that is not necessary UTC but could be in any timezone (and such timezone is not given as information, you must remember somewhere or ignore) seems the most useless class ever.